# Canvas rotation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform

If someone has the answer could you help me, please?
I have 2 images - background similar to arc and arrow. And i need to move arrow image over background image like this is a clock ticker arrow. So i need :

1. Rotate arrow to make it parallel to current tick on the arc
2. Move arrow to the next point

For this i need to use Canvas object in JavaScript and its method transform - this will allow to move arrow and rotate it.

The question is : how to use canvas.transform method to rotate (and desirable move) arrow around the arc? And which values and what relation between them should be in this case :

```
contextData.clearRect (0, 0, contextData.canvas.width, contextData.canvas.height);
contextData.save ();
contextData.translate(indicatorData.width () / 2, indicatorData.height () / 2);
contextData.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);  // the question is HERE
contextData.drawImage(rotationArrow, -rotationArrow.width / 2, -rotationArrow.height / 2);
contextData.restore ();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost forgot ... i found the answer, it works and this is the final code. To make it worked in IE you should add excanvas library from Google and to fix some IE8 issues you need to add compatibility meta tag :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
   <title>Canvas</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="indicator">
   <img class="image" src="usage_icon_electro.png" alt="" />
   <img class="pointer" src="usage_electro_pointer.png" alt="" />
   <canvas width="120" height="120" id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var indicatorClass = {

   timerHandle : 0,
   timerDelay : 10,

   rotationIncrement : 1,
   rotationStep : 0,
   rotationSteps : 50,
   rotationRadius : 35,

   angleCurrent : 5,
   angleDelta : 150,

   directionClockwise : true,

   canvasIndicator : null,
   canvasPointer : null,
   canvasContext : null,

   getRadianAngle : function (degreeValue) {
      return degreeValue * Math.PI / 180;
   },

   initCanvas : function (optionList) {

      try {

         var canvasData = $ ('.indicator #canvas').get (0);

         if ($.browser.msie) {
            canvasData = document.createElement('canvas');
            $ (canvasData)
               .attr ('width', 120)
               .attr ('height', 120)
               .attr ('id', 'canvas')
               .appendTo('.indicator');
            canvasData = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvasData);
            /*
            var metaCompatible = document.createElement('meta');
            $ (metaCompatible)
               .attr ('http-equiv', 'X-UA-Compatible')
               .attr ('content', 'IE=EmulateIE7')
               .prependTo('head');
            */
            //$ ('head').prepend ('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />');
//alert ($ ('head').html ());
         }

         indicatorClass.canvasIndicator = $ ('.indicator');
         indicatorClass.canvasPointer = $ ('.indicator .pointer').get (0);
         indicatorClass.canvasContext = canvasData.getContext ("2d");

         $.extend (indicatorClass, optionList);

         var angleMax = indicatorClass.angleCurrent + indicatorClass.angleDelta;
         indicatorClass.setRotationAngle (510);

         indicatorClass.timerHandle = setInterval(function () { 
            if (indicatorClass.angleCurrent > angleMax) {
               clearInterval (indicatorClass.timerHandle);
            }
            indicatorClass.angleCurrent += indicatorClass.rotationIncrement;
            indicatorClass.rotationStep += indicatorClass.rotationIncrement;
            indicatorClass.setRotation (); 
         }, indicatorClass.timerDelay);

      } catch (exceptionData) {
         alert ('Indicator is not loaded');
      }
   },

   getCircleCoords : function (stepIndex) {

      var centerX = indicatorClass.canvasIndicator.width () / 2;
      var centerY = indicatorClass.canvasIndicator.height () / 2;
      var coordValues = {
         currentX : (centerX + indicatorClass.rotationRadius * Math.cos (2 * Math.PI * stepIndex / indicatorClass.rotationSteps)),
         currentY : (centerY + indicatorClass.rotationRadius * Math.sin (2 * Math.PI * stepIndex / indicatorClass.rotationSteps))
      }

      return coordValues;
   },

   setRotationAngle : function (angleValue) {

      indicatorClass.canvasContext.translate(indicatorClass.canvasIndicator.width () / 2, indicatorClass.canvasIndicator.height () / 2);

      for (var currentAngle = 90; currentAngle <= 720; currentAngle++) {

         var sin = Math.sin(currentAngle * Math.PI / 360);  
         var cos = Math.cos(currentAngle * Math.PI / 360);
         var deltaX = indicatorClass.directionClockwise ? -sin : sin;
         var deltaY = indicatorClass.directionClockwise ? sin : -sin;

         if (currentAngle > angleValue) {
            indicatorClass.canvasContext.transform(cos, deltaY, deltaX, cos, 0, 0);
            return false;
         }
      }
   },

   setTransform : function () {

      var sin = Math.sin(indicatorClass.rotationStep * Math.PI / indicatorClass.rotationSteps);  
      var cos = Math.cos(indicatorClass.rotationStep * Math.PI / indicatorClass.rotationSteps);
      var deltaX = indicatorClass.directionClockwise ? -sin : sin;
      var deltaY = indicatorClass.directionClockwise ? sin : -sin;

      //indicatorClass.canvasContext.clearRect (0, 0, indicatorClass.canvasContext.canvas.width, indicatorClass.canvasContext.canvas.height);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.save ();
      //indicatorClass.canvasContext.translate(indicatorClass.canvasIndicator.width () / 2, indicatorClass.canvasIndicator.height () / 2);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.transform(cos, deltaY, deltaX, cos, 0, 0);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.clearRect (-screen.width, -screen.height, screen.width, screen.height);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.drawImage(indicatorClass.canvasPointer, -indicatorClass.canvasPointer.width / 2, -indicatorClass.canvasPointer.height - indicatorClass.rotationRadius);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.restore ();
   },

   setRotation : function () {

      var currentAngle = indicatorClass.directionClockwise ? indicatorClass.angleCurrent : -indicatorClass.angleCurrent;

      indicatorClass.canvasContext.save ();
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.rotate(indicatorClass.getRadianAngle (currentAngle));
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.clearRect (-screen.width, -screen.height, screen.width, screen.height);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.drawImage(indicatorClass.canvasPointer, -indicatorClass.canvasPointer.width / 2, -indicatorClass.canvasPointer.height - indicatorClass.rotationRadius);
      indicatorClass.canvasContext.restore ();
   }

}

window.onload = function () {
   indicatorClass.initCanvas ();
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.indicator {
   width:120px;
   height:120px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   text-align:center;
   position:relative;
}
.indicator .pointer {
   visibility:hidden;
}
.indicator #canvas {
   z-index:10000;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When posting an answer it is best to include a **minimal** example. You shouldn't include everything.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of fooling around with a transformation matrix, use the helper function .rotate

Doing this will let you rotate an object about its center

```
contextData.save()
contextData.translate(indicatorData.width() / 2, indicatorData.height() / 2) // ASSUMING this  is the object you want to rotate around the center of and that it is being drawn at 0,0
contextData.rotate(1.57) // 1.57 radians = about 90 degrees
contextData.drawImage(rotationArrow, -rotationArrow.width / 2, -rotationArrow.height / 2);
contextData.restore()
```

Comment: Rotate method is used to modify object's place in a space so it affects any other methods which can be applied to the object and they will be working wrong. Usually rotate method should be used only for cameras which are rotating around object to create illusion of perspective.